# How to compare two dataframe columns(same data not required)?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compare if the columns of two dfs are same not the data/Values

df1

```
         A       B       

    0   45      25

    1   46      26

    2   47      27
```

df 2

```
        B       A       

    0   45      25

    1   46      26

    2   47      27
```

I just want to check if both dfs have same columns and not data

I have tried to convert into list and series objects and then compare
Its giving me

```
    ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled dataframe objects
```

Comment: How working `df1.sort_index(axis=1) == df2.sort_index(axis=1)` ?

Comment: df1.columns == df2.columns

Comment: @min2bro with OP's example this will return `[False False]`

Comment: @Adam.Er8 True, Best way to convert that into set first and then compare set(df1.columns) == set(df2.columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get column names into a `set` and compare the sets:

```py
print(set(df1.columns) == set(df2.columns))
```

Full example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
         A       B       

    0   45      25

    1   46      26

    2   47      27"""), sep="\s+")

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
        B       A       

    0   45      25

    1   46      26

    2   47      27"""), sep="\s+")

print(set(df1.columns) == set(df2.columns))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1.columns.difference(df2.columns).size == 0
```